# Updating UITableView rows from Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am fetching or querying all the entries from my database (core-data) at three different times in my code, which I find to be an inefficient approach to writing the code.

The method  `_walks = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] getAllWalks];` helps getting all the entries from the database in the form of `NSArray`.

I call `_walks = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] getAllWalks];` for the first time in the `viewDidLoad` method, so that I can get all the entries when I launch my app.

Next, I call `_walks = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] getAllWalks];` when I click on the add button, which invokes the `(IBAction)addAction:(id)sender` method, so that my entry gets updated in the `TableViewCells`.

Lastly, I call `_walks = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] getAllWalks];` in the `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method, in order to update the row count, so that the row count remains inline with the entries in database event after I delete my entries.

Please let me know how I can avoid fetching all the entries three times. Also let me know if I have not followed good practice in this code.

[Project](https://github.com/ndagrawal/CoreDataiOS/tree/master/DogWalk)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DatabaseManager.h"
#import "Walks.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *walks;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize walks = _walks;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] simpleAddaDog];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    _walks = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] getAllWalks];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
- (IBAction)addAction:(id)sender {
    [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager]addWalk:[NSDate date]];
    _walks = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] getAllWalks];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    _walks = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager]getAllWalks];
    return _walks.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[_walks[indexPath.row] date]
                                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                          timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSLog(@"dateString = %@",dateString);
    cell.textLabel.text = dateString;
    return cell;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return TRUE;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        Walks *walkToRemove = _walks[indexPath.row];
        [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager]deleteTheWalks:walkToRemove];
        [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    [_tableView endUpdates];
    }
}


@end
```

**Core-data stack:**

```
//
//  DatabaseManager.m
//  DogWalk
//
//  Created by Nilesh Agrawal on 11/9/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Nilesh Agrawal. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DatabaseManager.h"
#import "Dog.h"
#import "MyConstants.h"


static DatabaseManager *_sharedInstance;
@implementation DatabaseManager
@synthesize persistantStore =_persistantStore;
@synthesize managedContext = _managedContext;
@synthesize managedObject =_managedObject;
@synthesize managedObjectModel =_managedObjectModel;


+(DatabaseManager *)sharedDatabaseManager{
    @synchronized(self){
        if(_sharedInstance==nil){
            _sharedInstance = [[DatabaseManager alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return _sharedInstance;
}

-(id)init{
    if(self = [super init]){

    }
    return self;
}

-(NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory{

    /*
        to get the location of the persistant store.
     */

    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]lastObject];

}

-(NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel{

    //checkif the managedObjectModel is null otherwise create a new one.
    if(_managedObjectModel !=nil){
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"DogWalk" withExtension:@"momd"];

    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*)persistantStoreCoordinator{
    //first check if the persistant store is nil or not, if not nill then return that one.
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistantStoreCoordinator=nil;

    //if the persistant store is nill, then create a new one.
    //Adding the managedObejct Model to the persistant store.
    persistantStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DogWalk.sqlite"];
    NSError *err=nil;
    //Adding the store to the persistant store co-ordinator.
    if(![persistantStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&err]){
        //in case if error occurs.
        NSLog(@"Error,=%@ErrorInfo= %@",err.description,err.userInfo);
    }
    return persistantStoreCoordinator;
}


-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    if(_managedContext!=nil){
        return _managedContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistantStoreCoordinator = [self persistantStoreCoordinator];
    if(persistantStoreCoordinator==nil){
        return nil;
    }
    _managedContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]init];
    [_managedContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistantStoreCoordinator];
    return _managedContext;
}

-(void)simpleAddaDog{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSString *dogName = @"Tommy";
    Dog *dog =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Dog" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    dog.name = dogName;
    [context save:nil];
}

-(void)addWalk:(NSDate *)date{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchedRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    /*
     fetch the first dog and then add walks to it .
     */
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Dog" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchedRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchedRequest error:nil];
    Dog *dog = fetchedObjects[0];
    Walks *walk = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Walks" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    walk.date = date;
    NSMutableOrderedSet *walks = [dog.walks mutableCopy];
    [walks addObject:walk];
    dog.walks = walks.copy;
    [context save:nil];
}


-(NSArray *)getAllWalks{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Dog" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    if((long)fetchedObjects.count < 0){
        return nil;
    }
    NSArray *dogArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    if((long)fetchedObjects.count>0){
        Dog *dog = fetchedObjects[0];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestDog = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionDog = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Walks" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequestDog setEntity:entityDescriptionDog];
        fetchRequestDog.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dog==%@",dog];
        dogArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestDog error:nil];
        NSLog(@"dog name = %@, dog Array Count = %ld",dog.name, dogArray.count);
    }
    return dogArray;
}

-(void)deleteTheWalks:(Walks *)WalkToRemove{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedContext =[self managedContext];
    [managedContext deleteObject:WalkToRemove];
    [managedContext save:nil];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, take `_walks` as `NSMutableArray` so when you add new `walk`s, you can directly add to the array and reload the table.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *walks;
```

In `viewDidLoad`, fetch the array only once.

```
_walks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] getAllWalks]];
```

Your `IBAction` method should look like the one below. Your database manager will return a `walks` object which you are directly adding to the array, so no need to fetch data from the database.

```
- (IBAction)addAction:(id)sender {
    [_walks addObject:[[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager]addWalk:[NSDate date]]];
    //_walks = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] getAllWalks];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

No need to fetch data in `numberOfRowsInSection:`; simply return your array count:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _walks.count;
}
```

In `DatabaseManager.m`, when saving context, return the same object after adding:

```
-(Walks *)addWalk:(NSDate *)date{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchedRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    /*
     fetch the first dog and then add walks to it .
     */
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Dog" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchedRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchedRequest error:nil];
    Dog *dog = fetchedObjects[0];
    Walks *walk = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Walks" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    walk.date = date;
    NSMutableOrderedSet *walks = [dog.walks mutableCopy];
    [walks addObject:walk];
    dog.walks = walks.copy;
    [context save:nil];
    return walk;
}
```

Now a `walks` object will be added to your array. Now just reload the table.